# Get point's y coordinate on svg path

Tags: svg, path, coordinates, point

I guess I need to add some explanation, that I want to ask this question, because too short question doesn't quality standards... funny...

So, here is the question:
How I can get the 'y' coordinate of the point on svg path at a specific 'x' coordinate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well this is not straightforward, because a path could have multiple points with the specified `x` coordinate.

There is no built-in function in the SVG DOM to do this.  One solution is to step along the path segments and do the maths yourself.

Alternatively, there is a built in function on `SVGPathElement` called `getPointAtLength(len)`.  You pass in a length along the path and it will return the x,y coords at that point.  You could step along the path length and work out where the x coordinate crosses your desired `x`.  You can get the path length from the `SVGPathElement.getTotalLength()` function.  It's a bit of a kludge and you have to be careful you don't miss points where the curve bends near your `x`.  But it should work.

[See here for more information on these functions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement)

Comment: I thought about stepping along the path length before, but tried to avoid it because of multiple points. Although finally I ended up with this approach, which in my case turned out to work fine.

Comment: I just added this to my code, but it's incredibly slow. It obviously depends heavily on the step size - I played around with it and put it to a point below which it becomes too inprecise, and still it's cutting my FPS in half.
Any other ideas? I found this, which is kinda cool, but a bit overkill: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8027637

Comment: That code you pointed at uses `getPointAtLength()` also.  It sounds like you might be using a fixed step size.  What you should be doing is using a coarse step until you find the `x` points either side of your search `x`.  Then estimate the next length based on where your search x falls in that range.  It should only take you a few guesses to get within an accurate tolerance.

Comment: I think it's probably better to binary search your path for the desired X point to within a given tolerance

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a similar problem and Paul's answer really helped me.

Just to further illustrate @Paul LeBeau's answer, here is a little demo:

```js
let path = document.getElementById("path");
let svg = document.getElementById("svg");

// The first important function getTotalLength
let totalLength = path.getTotalLength();
let intersections = 27;

for(var i = 0; i <= intersections; i ++){
  let distance = i * 1/intersections * totalLength;
  
  // The second important function getPointAtLength
  let point = path.getPointAtLength(distance);
  addCircleToSVG(point.x, point.y);
  addTextToSVG(point.x, point.y);
}

function addCircleToSVG(x, y){
  let circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'circle');
  circle.setAttribute("cx", x);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", y);
  circle.setAttribute("r", "5");
  circle.setAttribute("fill", "#8888ff");
  svg.appendChild(circle);
}

function addTextToSVG(x, y){
  let text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'text');
  text.setAttribute("x", x + 10);
  text.setAttribute("y", y);
  text.setAttribute("fill", "orange");
  text.innerHTML = Math.round(y);
  svg.appendChild(text);
}
```

```css
svg{
  width:auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1184.25 455.99">
  <path id="path" class="st0" d="M0.18,455.53c0,0,73-311,128-311s86,276,122,287s52-22,112-25s114,16,146,18s34,20,64,16s45-144,93-133
 s55-21,88-17s58,151,85,149s103-13,128-8s48-21,85-19c37,2,133,43,133,43" fill="#666666"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all the points of your path, I believe a more performant solution than stepping through the path might be to search the `d` attribute of your path for the specific x coordinate you are looking for. Then capture the y coordinate using regexp. The regexp could be used like so:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`${x} ((\d*.\d*))`)
const match = regex.exec(d)
```