# How to get intersection point(x,y) on SVG path

Tags: svg, path, coordinates, point

I have the SVG path, and I want to get point's y coordinate.

[image]
[image]

SVG line:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="340" viewBox="0 0 1920 340">
  <path clip-rule="evenodd" fill="none" stroke="#B3B3B3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M-.5 60.3c88.8-42 232.2-89.1 355.2-34.4C549.3 112.5 640.3 163 720.3 192.4c80 29.4 278.9 116.9 451.3 61.4 172.3-55.4 328-112.5 568.3-23.2 100.1 43 151.4 65.8 179.6 79.3"/>
</svg>
```

I try [this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53725183/11240898), but it doesn't fit my need. I think `path.getTotalLength()` is not great for my question.

How can I do?

---

Update:

What my project want to do: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reginna/udt20p6q/22)

I have no idea how red points can match the line for each device size.

Comment: I suggest you show us the code you've written to try to implement things along the lines of the answer you've found and then describe exactly why it doesn't work i.e. what does it do and what did you want it to do instead.

Comment: Ok, it's my fail. I update my description.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you try [paperjs](http://paperjs.org/). It’s a JS graphics library that uses HTML `<canvas>` elements as its graphics context(s). Here’s an example using your curve and a vertical line at `mouse.x`, which intersections shown.

```js
let wave_path
let bounds

window.onload = function() {
  //paper is a library for working with canvases; it's like a graphics library that works with a canvas
  //as its GUI window. Each canvas context is its own PaperScope, and the global paper variable is a reference
  //to the currently active PaperScope.
  paper.setup(document.getElementById('paper-canvas'))

  //import wave svg. however, if you integrate paperjs into your page, you might as well draw the curve directly onto the
  //canvas with paper, rather than creating an invisible svg element that you then import.
  let wave_svg = paper.project.importSVG(document.getElementById('svg-wave'))
  wave_svg.visible = true // Turn off the effect of display:none

  //fit wave into paper canvas
  bounds = paper.view.bounds
  wave_svg.fitBounds(bounds)

  wave_path = wave_svg.children[0] //get contained path
  wave_path.strokeColor = 'black'
  wave_path.fillColor = null

  //set event handlers on paper canvas
  paper.view.onMouseMove = mouse_move
}

function mouse_move(event) {
  let mouse_location = event.point

  //clear canvas before redrawing
  paper.project.clear()

  //when creating a graphical object with paper, it automatically gets drawn to the canvas at the end of an event handler

  //draw vertical line to intersect with
  let line = new paper.Path(new paper.Point(mouse_location.x, 0), new paper.Point(mouse_location.x, bounds.height))
  line.strokeColor = 'black'

  //redraw wave path
  new paper.Layer(wave_path)

  //draw intersections
  let intersections = line.getIntersections(wave_path)
  for (intersection of intersections) {
    let circle = new paper.Path.Circle(intersection.point, 5)
    circle.strokeColor = 'red'
    circle.fillColor = 'white'
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>SVG Intersection Demo</title>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-core.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <svg id="svg-wave" style="display:none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="340">
    <path clip-rule="evenodd" fill="none" stroke="#B3B3B3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M-.5 60.3c88.8-42 232.2-89.1 355.2-34.4C549.3 112.5 640.3 163 720.3 192.4c80 29.4 278.9 116.9 451.3 61.4 172.3-55.4 328-112.5 568.3-23.2 100.1 43 151.4 65.8 179.6 79.3"/>
  </svg>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
   <canvas id="paper-canvas" style="width:80%;"></canvas>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```