# How to get tangent at each point on SVG curve?

Tags: math, svg, curve

How do I get the tangent at each point on the curve below, without college-level mathematical knowledge?

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <path d="M31,15 c-13.30195,-6.65097 -29.40706,14.86506 -18.5,22.5 2.12549,1.48785 5.0285,1.5 7.5,1.5 25.3029,0 6.72535,-25.22535 -3.5,-15" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="none"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Well, it's pretty darn complicated.  Do you just want the tangents for the specific points named in the `c` command (easier) or for *any* arbitrary point on the resulting cubic polybezier curve (harder)?

Comment: Only the specific points.

Comment: "without college-level mathematical knowledge" - TLDR: you don't. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863528/calculating-tangent-point-on-arc-from-a-known-arc-point But you need to know the points first, which the SVG doesn't exactly give you easily. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633718/get-points-y-coordinate-on-svg-path

Comment: Right, plus you're using relative points and a polybezier (multiple bezier commands strung together) making it even trickier.  This is like college-level math *and* CS.  The first tangent is easy, it's the slope of the first relative control point coordinates(-6.65097/-13.30195).  After that it gets harder.

Comment: Besides converting to absolute coordinates, does SVG have a way to represent the same curves in a format that makes it easier to calculate the tangents?  If so, I can update the question with the curves in that format.  Anything to make the calculation easier.

Comment: if you have a path made only with C commands you can draw a line from the last control point of the previous courve to the first control point of the next curve. This line is tangent to the path

Comment: @enxaneta I've illustrated what I think you suggest, and it doesn't seem to actually give the tangent of any point: https://i.imgur.com/j8Od5Mp.png The tangents are hand-drawn and may be slightly inaccurate, but I think it's still obvious they are not similar to your proposed line.

Comment: Upon further research it appears that my hand-drawn "tangents" are at right angles to the real tangents.  Just keep that in mind.